# is it necessary the network when CD-ROM install ubuntu 16.04

Tags: server, system-installation

is it necessary the network when CD-ROM install ubuntu 16.04

I install ubuntu 16.04 server with cd-rom

the install log says:

```
Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'
```

it does doesnot exist , the dir update or InRelease

```
ls /var/www/html/ubuntu/dists/
stable  unstable  xenial
```

```
ls /var/www/html/ubuntu/dists/xenial/
main  Release  Release.gpg  restricted
```

and it has no network.

So is it necessary the mirror of update or the network when install ubuntu ?

I also find the install log :

```
May  7 07:09:36 in-target: E: Unable to locate package language-pack-en
May  7 07:09:36 /bin/in-target: warning: /target/etc/mtab won't be updated since it is a symlink.
May  7 07:09:36 pkgsel: finishing up
May  7 07:09:36 pkgsel: dpkg-query -W language-pack-en failed; assuming incomplete language support
May  7 07:09:36 net/hw-detect.hotplug: Detected hotpluggable network interface ens3
May  7 07:09:36 net/hw-detect.hotplug: Detected hotpluggable network interface lo
May  7 07:09:50 main-menu[281]: (process:29708): dpkg-query: no packages found matching language-pack-en
```

It can not find the package language-pack-en

maybe the cd-rom has no the package

does it do someting with the mirror us.archive.ubuntu.com  or no network ?

can I install an OS system ubuntu 16.04 without network properly?

what about 18 or 20 version?

***update***:

this is the ISO link where I download.

```
http://releases.ubuntu.com/16.04/ubuntu-16.04.6-server-amd64.iso
```

Comment: Please provide a link to the .iso you are using. Most Ubuntu Server 16.04 images don't fit upon a CD-ROM.

Comment: http://releases.ubuntu.com/16.04/ubuntu-16.04.6-server-amd64.iso

Comment: That image is 873MB, It won't fit on a CD-ROM. Was it perhaps a DVD? Or a different image? Details matter. That image carries all the packages you need, no internet is needed. Smaller (netboot) images must download essential packages from the network. Install .iso images do NOT have extra packages. If you want to use the server as, well, a server that does something useful, then you will need a network connection.